# Remove entire objects by array of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects that contains metadata and looks similar to this.

**Data:**

```
metadata:[ 
  { matchid: '1', region: 'europe' }, 
  { matchid: '2', region: 'africa' },
  { matchid: '3', region: 'asia' },
]
```

I have an endpoint setup to receive an array of IDS `['1', '2']` which would the remove all the objects containing these IDS.

This is my current query:

**Query to remove objects**

```
xx.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    $pullAll: {
        "metadata.matchid": {
           $in: req.body.matches
        }
    }
)
```

I am expecting both objects with the ids of 1 and 2 to be removed

**Expected Results:**

```
metadata:[ 
  { matchid: '3', region: 'asia' },
]
```

I am recieving an error I have never seen before it is an object that says codeName: "BadValue"

Comment: `$pullAll` removes only the elements in the array that match the specified value exactly you given, including order. And it starts with an empty operand expression `( { } )` . So, maybe query like this: `xx.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $pullAll: { "metadata.matchid": [{ $in: req.body.matches }], }, });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) says:

> The `$pullAll` operator removes all instances of the specified values from an existing array. Unlike the `$pull` operator that removes elements by specifying a query.

`$pullAll` requires and exact match and `$pull` is like to use a filter. So you can use `$pull` in this way.

```
yourModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    $pull: {
        metadata:{
           matchid: { $in: req.body.matches}
        }
    }
)
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/40k1DXB8Q2b)